# Which version is pip?

Tags: python

`pip` is in my `/usr/bin/pip` folder.  May I know for which Python installation is that?

I want to run pip to add some packages for my Python 3.4 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip is for use with Python 2.7. Pip3 is for use with Python 3.x.